# How to break out of loop in subprocess in python

Tags: python, global-variables, multiprocessing

I feel like this should be an easy solution but it's the end of the day and I'm brain-dead.
I am currently spawning a couple of processes, one process is receiving and storing data to a file. Another is parsing the data and third is waiting for user input to know when to stop the storing of data.

What I need to know how to do is breakout of my while loop. I'd like to not use global variables set by the parent process but if that is required I can do that.
Right now my code looks something like this:

```
while(packetReceived < totalToReceive):
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(packetSize)
```

My thoughts were something like this:

```
breakout = 0
while(packetReceived < totalToReceive || breakout != 0):
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(packetSize)
```

but then I need to set breakout somehow. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're using `multiprocessing`, you can't rely on child processes having access to global variables from the parent process. On Windows you'll always have separate copies in each process; on Unix, you'll sometimes have separate copies, sometimes shared copies, and sometimes shared copies that aren't refcounted properly and can vanish out from underneath you. Neither of these is what you want.

Comment: I had an idea of that and that is why I was trying to avoid globals. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't share state just by having a global variable in the parent process. This may appear to work, but it only works sometimes; it's neither reliable nor predictable. Except that on Windows, it reliably and predictably never works; each child will always have its own independent copy of the flag, and therefore you will never quit.

If you really want to do this by sharing a variable, see [Sharing state between processes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) in the docs, but the short version is: You create a `multiprocessing.Value`. And then you use a `multiprocessing.Condition` to protect that value against races, because otherwise, there's no guarantee that the child processes will ever see a change from the parent.

Of course you can fake this by, e.g. creating an `mmap` of minimum size and just using `m[0]` as a flag and `m.flush()` instead of the condition, but that's not really any simpler.

The alternative way to do this is to use a [`multiprocessing.Pipe`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) or similar to pass a "shut down now" message. The child processes can each spawn a thread to block on the pipe, or you can toss the pipe and your socket into a `select` together, or all the other usual tricks.

There may be another, simpler option in this case: don't use `multiprocessing` in the first place. Clearly your background task is not CPU-bound, since it's just looping around reading from a socket, so why not just `threading`?

Also, it strikes me that you might be able to simplify your design in other ways, which could remove this problem entirely. Do you need a file between the reading and processing jobs instead of, say, a queue, or even just a direct sequential pipeline? Can you toss the user input and the socket into the same event loop (plain old `select` if user input is `stdin` and you don't care about Windows; use a `QSocket` instead of a `socket.socket` if user input is a Qt GUI; `twisted` if you're willing to learn `twisted`; etc.). Or, is there real user input, or just "quit now" (or "shut down the socket and process the remaining messages now"), which you could handle with ^C?

Comment: This may solve my problem. I'll test it out and mark it answered if it works for me. Thanks!

Comment: @pri0ritize: I had a few more thoughts that I added to the end of the answer; if any of them sound helpful, but you need more info, let me know and I can go into more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a multiprocessing variable, consider checking for the presence of "poison pill" to break out of your loop.

For example, change:

```
data, addr = sock.recvfrom(packetSize)
```

to something like:

```
received = sock.recvfrom(packetSize)
if received is None:
    break
data, addr = received
```

You can signal the process to break out of its loop by sending it a `None` value. I'm not sure if your `sock` can send/receive `None`, but the general idea is the same.

Comment: That's a great idea but it won't work for my situation. I'm not in control of what is being sent into the socket.